# Image Blob not adding to the mySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I tried so many times and tried changing things and still not working, It still add and throw null here's the code of the HTML, PHP and also JS (just incase needed). I already tried to do some of the methods on github and stack overflow and still doesn't work. I hope someone can help me with this issue I really appreciate it thank you

[image]

[image]

```html
          <!-- 8 avatar/profile picture -->       
          <div class="tab">
            <div class="file-upload">
                Profile Picture:
                <button class="file-upload-btn" type="button" onclick="$('.file-upload-input').trigger( 'click' )">Select Picture</button>
                <p style="font-size: 10px;">Please upload a decent photo, This will go under verification.</p>   
                <div class="image-upload-wrap">
                        <input id='avatar' class="file-upload-input" type='file' name="avatar" onchange="readURL(this);" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
                      <div class="drag-text">
                          <h3>Upload a Photo</h3>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="file-upload-content">
                        <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
                            <div class="image-title-wrap">
                                <button type="button" onclick="removeUpload()" class="remove-image"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            <br/>
                            </div>
                  </div>
                  <script src="./assets/js/add_photo.js"></script>
            </div>                        
          </div>
```

```php
//Profile Picture
$avatar = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
$avatar_name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$xavatar = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($avatar)));   

//I did not include other data since it is unrelated to this topic
$sql = "INSERT INTO users_tb(user_avatar)VALUES('$xavatar')";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
':user_avatar' => $xavatar
]);
```

```js
//avatar
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

  var areader = new FileReader();

  areader.onload = function(e) {
    $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

    $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('.file-upload-content').show();
    // <span class="image-title">Uploaded Image</span>
    //$('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
  };

  areader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

} else {
  removeUpload();
}
}

function removeUpload() {
$('.file-upload-input').replaceWith($('.file-upload-input').clone());
$('.file-upload-content').hide();
$('.image-upload-wrap').show();
}
$('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragover', function () {
      $('.image-upload-wrap').addClass('image-dropping');
  });
  $('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragleave', function () {
      $('.image-upload-wrap').removeClass('image-dropping');
});
```

Comment: You are building a full SQL string without any parameters, but then trying to use it with a parameter, I wouldn’t be surprised if there’s an error being emitted there. Do you have PHP and MySQL error reporting enabled?

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO users_tb(user_avatar)VALUES('$xavatar')";`...you seem to have misunderstood how to use prepared statements and parameters. You should have a PDO error complaining that the number of parameters doesn't match. Try `$sql = "INSERT INTO users_tb(user_avatar)VALUES(:user_avatar)";` instead so the placeholder is correctly replaced with the parameter value from the array when the query is executed.

Comment: P.S. The above will help, but your description of the issue is so vague that there may well be other problems too. It's unclear whether you've done any detailed debugging to try and narrow down the issue - mostly it makes it sound like you've spent the time thrashing about trying all sorts of random (but unspecified) stuff from anywhere you can find online, in a seemingly unscientific and unsystematic way. That's not a good approach to solving programming problems.

Comment: I just CTRL + Z and now everything is working and im not sure how it fixed.

Comment: Anyways, I'll just follow the second comment. thank you for the advice!

Comment: Images do not really belong into the database in the first place - they belong into the file system. You would need a really good reason to stick the image data itself into the database - so what is yours, here?

Comment: CBroe, Its only for a small school project, not gonna be tested by a lot of people so i made it more easier and since im only using a free hosting file upload is too slow and very limited that's why database is my second option that's why i use blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
get the $_FILE variable without base64encode function ( you have to use it when you take it from your database )

```
$avatar = file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
```

Surprised that there is no sql error !? it seems to me that it should be like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users_tb(user_avatar)VALUES(:user_avatar)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute([
    ':user_avatar' => $xavatar
    ]);
```

you must assign the value of user_avatar only during the execute statment